# How to fix this syntax issue?

Tags: javascript

```js
const person = (firstName, lastName) => 
{
  first: firstName,
  last: lastName
}
console.log(person("Jill", "Wilson"))
```

This code get a syntax error
Please let me know the correct code
Thanks

Comment: And the exact error is...?

Comment: @j08691 [`last:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) is not valid as part of a comma operator expression.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your object in brackets `()`. It is required if you are returning anonymous object right in arrow function.

```js
const person = (firstName, lastName) =>
({
  first: firstName,
  last: lastName
})
console.log(person("Jill", "Wilson"))
```

---

### Why?

It could not be possible to find difference between function and object. This is function in curly brackets:

```js
const myFn = () => {
   const someCode = "wow I'm in function. Not in Object!";
}
```

It has same syntax, same brackets, as the example you have provided.